# Problems with display nav properly

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

1. I'm having trouble with adding space to the hovered "home" right/left.
2. Adding proper spacing so after the hovered section of "home" appears that about and the other pages would follow.

CSS:

```
nav {
    width:460px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#0066ff;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 0 0 324px;
    position: fixed;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width:493px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

nav li {
        float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 0 0 24px;
    display: block;
    width: 51px;
    height: 50px;
}

nav li:first-child {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 15px 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
}

nav a:first-child {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    min-width:51px;
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    line-height:50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    min-width:51px;
    display:block;
    position: fixed;
    line-height:50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}


nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active {
    background: #929292;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}
```

This problem has been giving me headaches for hours.
[image: nav]

[Link Update](http://jsfiddle.net/nickhiebert/rna3Z/3/)

[image]
[image]

The blue space beside about can't happen.

Comment: Can you share the jsfiddle link. It will be easy to test

Comment: Sure, give me a moment

Comment: For some reason the blue background isn't showing. But please reference the image I already provided.

Comment: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nickhiebert/rna3Z/)

Comment: Please look at this one: [jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nickhiebert/rna3Z/1/)

Comment: Great, you can update your question with that info. I was about to say that first one is messing up cause you had the wrong type of comment block.

Comment: The fiddler is working. I'm still not clear on what you want. While hovering, do you want to add extra space to left and right? Wont that push the other elements too?

Comment: I want space between home so it's not touching the edge. Then right after after that, I want the spacing for about to appear the same. So there's no extra blue space when I hover over about. Does that make sense?

Comment: Between the hovers of "home" and "about" = no extra blue space between then besides the space between the selected link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick, your issue is in the `li:first-child` selector. Specifically the `padding` attribute, where it clears the padding, where you're missing the spacing.

- Many of your `:first-child` selectors are redundant, and don't need to be re-specified.
- Mixing `position:fixed` with `float:left` is generally not a good idea as your CSS will be fighting layout structure.
- You only need a `position:fixed` for the main container, the rest the nav's children will be relative to that.
- There's a lot of unnecessary padding and such, you should use your browser's DOM inspector to play with the layout.

Check this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rna3Z/5/)** that's cleaned it up.

[image: Navbar]

Comment: fixed needs to be there. The nav is apart of the header, I want it to be fixed in place as I scroll down.

Comment: Thank you! That's the exactly result I was looking for. I've been trying to fix this thing for a few hours and I think this should just be an hour tops of work. I'll try and implement this solution.

Comment: Just make sure that the first element after the `nav` has `margin-top: <heightOfNav>` so the fixed works out right. I bit of web dev intuition told me you probably wanted that centered horizontally and this sort of interaction.

Comment: I've gotten something like this close before, but not at this effect. I just need to tweek the code a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the time, a small `<div>` is placed to the left of the "home" link to push it over like so:

```
#fillerdiv{
width:20px;
background-color:#0066ff;
}
```

then you could place it like so:

```
<nav>
<ul>
<div id="fillerdiv"></div>
              <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

That produces this:
[image]
Or you could give the "home" button a specific class and add extra padding for it alone.

```
#home{
     padding-left:20px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
              <li id="home"> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I played around your code a bit and tried to simplify it. I hope you don't mind.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rna3Z/6/)

```
/* styles.css */
nav {       
    float: left;
   background: #0066ff; 
    border: 1px solid green;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;   
}

nav li {
    float: left;    
    display: block; 
}

nav a {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding:20px;   
color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a:link, nav ul li a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;  
    display:block;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a:active {
    background: #929292;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I guess it can be simplified further:)